# Spinner for date of birth (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, registration

I am creating a registration form for an application. I want to prompt the user to enter his date of birth through three spinners (DD-MM-YY).

This is my XML for the sign up/registration form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_signup"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email" />

       <requestFocus />

<EditText
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="First Name" />

<EditText
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/editTextLastName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Last Name" />

<EditText
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Confirm Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<EditText
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Age" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mynumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number +961"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Number" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_create"
             />

               </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```

You can see that there is an "Age" section (EditText) that I will delete and replace by the spinner one. What should the spinner section look like?

Comment: What is the issue exactly then?

Comment: What should i add to my code ?

Comment: @PareshMayani What should i add to my code ?

Comment: A bit off from your requirement, but maybe you can consider using `DatePicker` instead. Read [Android Developers' Guide on Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Comment: I didn't understand what is the issue exactly? I mean what are you trying to implement and facing an issue in it?

Comment: @RoyMourad why don't you try DatePicker instead of spinner